# visualstudio - How can I convert a object content to string

Tags: string, visual-studio, object, visual-studio-2012

I want to show the directory but the messagebox show this: **system.__ComObject**

```
 Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        filesystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        ThisDir = filesystem.GetFolder("F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\")

       '1st try
        MessageBox.Show(ThisDir.ToString())

       '2nd try
       Dim a As String = CType(ThisDir, String)
       MessageBox.Show(a)
  end sub
```

What i'm doing wrong?

thankyou

Comment: Why are you using that old COM technology? Take a look at the `System.IO.Directory` class in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to work with the FileSystemObject, you have to call the `Name` property to get the name of the folder:

```
MessageBox.Show(ThisDir.Name)
```

But i would recommend to use the .NET classes in the namespace `System.IO` like `System.IO.Directory`